# Java , Csv to json , jackson-dataformat-csv

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson

I am novice in java and  I want to convert csv file into json

I'am using the following code example to convert csv file into json file,
the things is, I have got an error on the" withSchema(bootstrap) "  it says : "The method with(CsvSchema) is undefined for the type ObjectReader" 
 and I do not know how to fix it, I have change maven dependencies to the version 2.9.0, try withtype(bootstrap) withCsvSchema(bootstap) but still not working .

Thanks

Here is the code :

```
package CsvData;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

public class csvjson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("/x/data.csv");
        File output = new File("/x/data.json");

        List<Map<?, ?>> data = readObjectsFromCsv(input);
        writeAsJson(data, output);
    }

    public static List<Map<?, ?>> readObjectsFromCsv(File file) throws IOException {
        CsvSchema bootstrap = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        MappingIterator<Map<?, ?>> mappingIterator = csvMapper.reader(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValues(file);

        return mappingIterator.readAll();
    }

    public static void writeAsJson(List<Map<?, ?>> data, File file) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(file, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the error message please

Comment: What's the contents of the returned `List<Map>`?

Comment: Did you try to find the JavaDoc for that ObjectReader class ?

Comment: @AlexT. it contains my csv data

Comment: @Jens the error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method with(CsvSchema) is undefined for the type ObjectReader

Comment: See if this blog is helpful: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I tried with version 2.2.1 and it works fine for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
```

Here is the Java method

```
public static List<Map<?, ?>> readObjectsFromCsv(File file) throws IOException {
    CsvSchema bootstrap = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    MappingIterator<Map<?, ?>> mappingIterator = csvMapper.reader(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValues(file);

    return  mappingIterator.readAll();
}
```

Even document says it works since 2.2 but dnt know why it is not working for 2.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Correct method name is withSchema

```
csvMapper.reader(Map.class).withSchema(bootstrap).readValues(file);
```